# In the AdminPanelProvider i want only admin can access

Tags: php, laravel-10, laravel-filament, filamentphp

```
public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
  {
    return $panel
    ->resources([
        config('filament-logger.activity_resource')
    ])
  }
```

I want to hide that resources from all user types except my admin.

Comment: `if (auth()->user()->type === 'admin')` ??

Comment: please elaborate your question what  do you mean only admin can access ?

Answer (score 0):

https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/installation#allowing-users-to-access-a-panel

By default, all `User` models can access Filament locally. However, when deploying to production, you must update your `App\Models\User.php` to implement the `FilamentUser` contract — ensuring that only the correct users can access your panel:

```php
public function canAccessPanel(Panel $panel): bool
{
    return str_ends_with($this->email, '@yourdomain.com') && $this->hasVerifiedEmail();
}
```